# UWP built with cordova and Ionic don't take hosts file into account

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, uwp, hosts

I am building an application with cordova and Ionic for Windows UWP.
When I run this code

```
this.http.post('htpp://myDomain.com/path/', data).toPromise().then(() => { ... });
```

It enters in the catch clause returning a response with 0 status.

I get this warning too, I don't know if it's related :

```
CONSOLE21301: serviceWorker.getRegistrations is rejected due to unsecure context or host restriction in ms-appx-web://microsoft.microsoftedge/assets/errorpages/dnserror.html?ErrorStatus=0x800C0005
```

My hosts file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost myDomain.com
```

Has someone an idea to fix this ?

Thanks By advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found !

running this command allows the uwp app to run requests to local servers !

```
CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt -a -n="[app PackageFullName]"
```